# Fully Rendering A User Control On An Ajax Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a UserControl I want to render programatically during an AJAX request, but the problem is that the `RenderControl` method is not calling any of the UserControl's events, such as PageLoad.

Here is my code:

```
TextWriter myTextWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myTextWriter);

ASP.Comment commentControl = (ASP.Comment)
LoadControl("CommentManage.ascx");
commentControl.Comment = comment;

commentControl.RenderControl(myWriter);
```

Am I missing a step? One solution I thought of was to place the PageLoad code into a public method and just call that, but I would like to call the PageLoad normally if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Where in the page lifecycle is this code being executed?

Comment: It is part of an AJAX request, so it is taking place in the `RaiseCallbackEvent` method.

Comment: I might suggest moving code that needs to execute before the control is rendered into a publicly accessible method, then have your `page_load` of the control call that method. What is happening in your load method?

Comment: I already typed in the question saying that I already figured that out but was looking for a better way. Anyway I think I will leave it like this...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the control to the page and it will catch up with the page life-cycle events.

```
Page.Controls.Add(commentControl);
```